# PHP SESSION for Username

Tags: php

I am trying to make part of my sequence build a chart based on logged in username using the following code, however no matter what I've tried I can't get it to work as the highlighted out line does?

```
<?php include("auth.php"); ?>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("***","***","***");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("***", $con);

*/ $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vw2014 WHERE username = 'Palendrone'"); /*

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vw2014 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."'"); */


etc....
```

Is this correct or am I missing something else?

Comment: Have you put `session_start()` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session doesn't seem started. Without this, you will not be able to grab your session information:

```
session_start()
```

Comment: This is the second line of code in the auth.php file shouldn't this suffice?

Comment: Did you try something like this: `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what's inside?

Comment: You certainly pointed me in the right direction, I realised the auth.php needed to be../auth.php as I had relocated them to an additional folder ! Thanks for the help, my own silly mistake which I didn't notice until now.